# I can't start my rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run my rails server in new created app, but everytime I wrote

> "rails server"

it tells me that i need gem named

> "byebug"

and when i try to install this gem this is result: [imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ronf6.png)

I had the rails server before but I reinstalled my pc and now I can't run it. I have 64bit windows 10.

I tried reinstall every rails spiece include mysql and nothing have changed.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You're running on Windows, so you'll need to follow the instructions you were given at the bottom of your screenshot to get and install the development kit that'll supply the tools needed to build the native-code (non-Ruby) parts of `byebug`.

Comment: Your answer is there at plain sight, please follow instructions in the error message.

Comment: I updated Paths and manualy install DevKit and yes there was problem. Thanks for help. I just don't red the error. So sorry for useful question.

Answer (score 0):

You error messages states "run bundle install to install missing gems".  On your prompt type "bundle install" and hit enter.  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows for Ruby on Rails development. You need to properly configure all the dependencies as the error shows.

Install or update your **development kit**, that serve as the building tools in Windows.

please follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit